# How to use For loop to print all items in python class

Tags: python, loops, class, for-loop

I have created a new class:

testing.py:

```
class student:
    def __init__(self, name, major, gpa):
        self.nm = name
        self.mj = major
        self.gp = gpa
```

then, I move to my working file testing.py:

```
from testing import student
student1=student("Marcos","Physics",3.99)
student2=student("Phillyp","Biology",2.99)
student3=student("Naim", "Architecture", 3.42)

for k in range(1,4):
    print(student(k).gp) <------- how do I merge this string with int!?!?
```

my final aim is to print out ALL the gpa of all students, so I know I need to do

```
print(student1.gp)
print(student2.gp)
print(student3.gp)
```

So how can I concatenate the k into the variable name to produce student1.gp, student2.gp etc?

Thank you all so much!

Comment: what do you mean exactly by fixing the loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

instead of this `for k in range(1,4):` you want to iterate over a list of all of your students:

```
students = [student1, student2, student3]
for student in students:
    print(student.gp)
```

EDIT

If you want to be able to reference the students by name, store them in a `dict`:

```
students = {'student1': student("Marcos","Physics",3.99),
            'student2': student("Phillyp","Biology",2.99),
            'student3': student("Naim", "Architecture", 3.42)}

for i in range(1, 4):
    print(students[f'student{i}'].gp)
    # if less than python 3.6
    # print(students['student{}'.format(i)].gp)
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but my ultimate aim is to know how to concatenate that k (integer) into  "student" (is this considered a string?)

Comment: @MT32 No it's not a string, it's a variable name. I would highly recommend you use a list to store your students.

Answer (score 1):

What you should be doing is putting all the objects in `list`. E.g.

```
from testing import student

student1 = student("Marcos","Physics",3.99)
student2 = student("Phillyp","Biology",2.99)
student3 = student("Naim", "Architecture", 3.42)

students = [student1, student2, student3]

for student in students:
    print(student.gp)
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion sir, but that is what I am currently doing. But Im actually looking for suggestions to concatenate the k in for loop into the variable name....